# Ubuntu Software Center not appearing

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu, software-center

I just installed Lubuntu on my cubieboard (cubieboard.org). I attempted to install Ubuntu Software Center from Synaptic Package Manager, and everything all went smoothly until I tried to open up software center and nothing appear. I tried to use command line 
`software-center`

Heres the output:

```
linaro@cubieboard2:~$ software-center
ERROR:root:DebFileApplication import
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from debfile import DebFileApplication, DebFileOpenError
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/debfile.py", line 25, in <module>
from softwarecenter.db.application import Application, AppDetails
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/application.py", line 27, in <module>
import softwarecenter.distro
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 197, in <module>
distro_instance = _get_distro()
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 172, in _get_distro
module = __import__(distro_module_name, globals(), locals(), [], -1)
ImportError: No module named linaro
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 128, in <module>
from softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app import SoftwareCenterAppGtk3
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 53, in <module>
from softwarecenter.db.application import Application
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/application.py", line 27, in <module>
import softwarecenter.distro
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 197, in <module>
distro_instance = _get_distro()
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 172, in _get_distro
module = __import__(distro_module_name, globals(), locals(), [], -1)
ImportError: No module named linaro
```

I tried to reinstall and it still gives me the same error,

`sudo apt-get remove software-center`

`sudo apt-get install software-center`

PS: Sorry for my bad english.

Updates:

```
linaro@cubieboard2:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal InRelease                           
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal Release     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Sources
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main armhf Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Sources
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal/main armhf Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal/universe armhf Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
linaro@cubieboard2:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal InRelease
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal Release
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Sources
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main armhf Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Sources
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal/main armhf Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal/universe armhf Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
```

```
linaro@cubieboard2:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-notify-0.7 python-pysqlite2
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/627 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  software-center
Authentication warning overridden.
(Reading database ... 60527 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace software-center 5.4.1.2 (using .../software-center_5.4.1.2_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement software-center ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Setting up software-center (5.4.1.2) ...
ERROR:root:DebFileApplication import
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from debfile import DebFileApplication, DebFileOpenError
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/debfile.py", line 25, in <module>
    from softwarecenter.db.application import Application, AppDetails
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/application.py", line 27, in <module>
    import softwarecenter.distro
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 197, in <module>
    distro_instance = _get_distro()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 172, in _get_distro
    module = __import__(distro_module_name, globals(), locals(), [], -1)
ImportError: No module named linaro
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/update-software-center", line 38, in <module>
    from softwarecenter.db.update import rebuild_database
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/update.py", line 33, in <module>
    from softwarecenter.backend.scagent import SoftwareCenterAgent
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/scagent.py", line 28, in <module>
    from softwarecenter.distro import get_distro, get_current_arch
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 197, in <module>
    distro_instance = _get_distro()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 172, in _get_distro
    module = __import__(distro_module_name, globals(), locals(), [], -1)
ImportError: No module named linaro
```

```
linaro@cubieboard2:~$ software-center
ERROR:root:DebFileApplication import
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from debfile import DebFileApplication, DebFileOpenError
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/debfile.py", line 25, in <module>
    from softwarecenter.db.application import Application, AppDetails
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/application.py", line 27, in <module>
    import softwarecenter.distro
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 197, in <module>
    distro_instance = _get_distro()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 172, in _get_distro
    module = __import__(distro_module_name, globals(), locals(), [], -1)
ImportError: No module named linaro
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 128, in <module>
    from softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app import SoftwareCenterAppGtk3
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 53, in <module>
    from softwarecenter.db.application import Application
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/application.py", line 27, in <module>
    import softwarecenter.distro
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 197, in <module>
    distro_instance = _get_distro()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 172, in _get_distro
    module = __import__(distro_module_name, globals(), locals(), [], -1)
ImportError: No module named linaro
```

Answer (score 2):

Run the below commands in terminal to reinstall software center,

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge software-center
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install software-center
sudo software-center
```

or replace last command with

```
software-center
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering the question, I updated the post still giving me the same errors.

Comment: Avinash can u explain what cud be the reason??

Comment: Fyi, I downloaded the image from http://docs.cubieboard.org/tutorials/a20-cubieboard_lubuntu_desktop_releases, tried to look up on google but couldn't find any solution.